# How to add ternary condition with select

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to list the selling price of product. Product `has_many` `product_varients` [sic], and `product_varients` belong to `product`. `Product` table has a column called `selling_price`. `Product_varients` table also has a field `selling_price`. If selling price is in `product_varients` table, it should take this `selling_price`, otherwise it should take `selling_price` from `product` table.

This is my code:

```
class Product
  has_many :product_varients, dependent: :destroy
  def selling_price_by_body_type vehicle
    self.product_varients.select {|pv| pv.body_type == vehicle.body_type}.first.try(:selling_price) || self.selling_price
  end
end
```

This is how I am calling the method:

```
product.selling_price_by_body_type(@vehicle)
```

This does not work for me. I want to modify it to using a ternary condition or `if` ... `else`.

Comment: What do you mean "not working"? Do you see any errors?

Comment: No errors, but getting value as nil if product_varients fields has selling_price value.

Comment: Do all product_varients have selling_price set?

Comment: No it is optional case. if selling_price present means display product_varients table else it should take the price from product table.

Comment: I mean can you debug the code to see the value of `self.product_varients.where(body_type: vehicle.body_type).first`? What does it return?

Comment: it returns product_varients array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
class Product
  has_many :product_varients, dependent: :destroy

  def selling_price_by_body_type(vehicle)
    self.product_varients.where(body_type: vehicle.body_type).first&.selling_price || self.selling_price
  end
end
```

Note:

- You can use `where` in place of `select { ... }.first` to reduce the number of records returned.
- `&.` is another way to write `.try()` in rails 5.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the `ternary operator` for the same:

```
class Product
 has_many :product_varients, dependent: :destroy
 def selling_price_by_body_type vehicle
        self.product_varients ? self.product_varients.select {|pv| pv.body_type == vehicle.body_type}.first.try(:selling_price) : self.selling_price
      end
end
```